# PHP: How to select values for each date in the database, even future dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a database with a table that has two fields: a date field (yyyy/mm/dd) and a value.

I want to pick only the values that correspond to each specific day.

So I want to work with all values that have 2014/07/30 date. And then 2014/07/31, and then 2014/08/01, and so on.

I know that I can select the specific date with something like:

```
$consulta="  SELECT fecha, monto
             FROM gasto 
             WHERE fecha = '2014/07/30'
             ";
```

**But how may I do automatically with every date? And even future dates?**

Ie. I want to sum all results and show them by date, like:

2014/07/30 = 10

2014/07/31 = 24

2014/08/01 = 12

etc...

Comment: and can't you use the ```>=``` operator? Or the ```between date1 and date2```?

Comment: Or just `SELECT fecha, monto FROM gasto ` ... no need of a `WHERE` condition

Comment: If you want to select records for *every* date then you're essentially selecting *every* record.  Just get rid of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I have clarified the question. BTW, I don't understand why the close vote or the minus 1. Just because the question seems to plain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum the results by date, then use a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT fecha, sum(monto) as summonto
FROM gasto 
GROUP BY fecha;
```

If you want the total sum for all dates, just use the `sum()` without the `group by`:

```
SELECT fecha, sum(monto) as summonto
FROM gasto ;
```

You can add a `where` clause to either query to restrict the particular dates.